SwiftUI: How to implement circular dismiss button for sheets in SwiftUI as shown in Apple HIG?
I'm trying to implement a sheet in SwiftUI that includes the circular dismiss button as shown in Apple's Human Interface Guidelines.
I've tried recreating it with a custom solution:
Button {
    dismiss()
} label: {
    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
        .font(.title)
        .foregroundStyle(.primary.opacity(0.6))
}

Is there a built-in way to get this circular dismiss button in SwiftUI sheets, or do I just go with the custom one?
I want to follow Apple's design guidelines while maintaining a native look and feel.

Checkout .bordered
